# CYPHER - Different COUNTs return the same result

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two counts using the following query.

```
MATCH (user: User {username : 'bar' })
MATCH (user)-[upvote : UPVOTED]->(:Post)
MATCH (user)-[downvote : DOWNVOTED]->(:Post)
RETURN COUNT(upvote) - COUNT(downvote)
```

It always returns `0` because both counts are the same value. I've ran the query separately for each count and they are indeed different (3 and 1) but together the query returns innacurate results.

**[UPDATE]**

Weirdly, when I run this query

```
MATCH (user : User {username : 'bar' })
MATCH (user)-[upvote : UPVOTED]->(:Post)
MATCH (user)-[downvote : DOWNVOTED]->(:Post)
RETURN COUNT(downvote)
```

It returns 3, while the expected output is 1. It is as if the larger `MATCH` is dominating the result

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the results from that query *before* adding the `COUNT`? Do you know what it's actually matching? That might give you an idea why.

Comment: I have tested the matches separately and it returns a list; 3 items for upvotes and 1 for downvotes. If I run the query with both matches together it returns two lists with 3 items in each. I can't confirm the contents of these returned items because the relationships have no properties.

Comment: And what's the count of each of them? 4?

Comment: Separate queries for only matches with one relationship type returns 3 for upvotes and 1 for downvotes. Together they both return 3.

I've also found one more quandry in the results and have updated the question with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j builds up rows as you perform MATCH and OPTIONAL MATCHES. They will be dependent upon the number of results from previous queries.

For example, let's say that a user has upvoted 3 but downvoted 1.

At the end of your MATCH for upvotes, the count of rows being built up is 3, each with the user, and each upvoted relationship.

But at the end of the MATCH for downvotes, the count of rows being built up is 3. Each row has: the user, one of the upvotes, and the single downvote:

```
user, up1, down1 
user, up2, down1 
user, up3, down1
```

Count of ups should be accurate, but count of downs will be 3 as well.

Note that this is also a performance hit: your query to get the downvotes for a user doesn't run once for the single user as you would expect, but 3 times, once for each row with a user (it just happens to be the same user in each row).

If you had 2 downvotes instead of one, then there would be 6 rows built up (3 x 2, each upvote paired with each possible downvote):

```
user, up1, down1
user, up1, down2
user, up2, down1
user, up2, down2
user, up3, down1
user, up3, down2
```

If you did a count of DISTINCT ups and DISTINCT downs at the end of your query, you should get right numbers, but the better way is to watch out for back-to-back matches (where the first match results in more than one row) and calculate the counts early like this:

```
MATCH (user : User {username : 'bar' })
MATCH (user)-[upvote : UPVOTED]->(:Post)
WITH user, COUNT(upvote) as upvotes
MATCH (user)-[downvote : DOWNVOTED]->(:Post)
RETURN upvotes, COUNT(downvote) as downvotes
```

The reason this works is that after the WITH in the middle, you only have 1 built up row: the user, with the upvote count. When we match on the downvotes, the rows built up will be the user with the upvote count with each downvote relationship: number of downvotes x 1, which will get you an accurate count when you run the COUNT function:

```
user, 3 as upvotes, down1
```

If you had two downvotes instead of one, it would be:

```
user, 3 as upvotes, down1
user, 3 as upvotes, down2
```

And so on.

In general, when you can, run your aggregations (count, collect, etc) between back-to-back MATCHES or OPTIONAL MATCHES instead of at the end (unless of course you know what you're doing and that the back-to-back matches are correct for your case). Visualize how neo4j is building up your rows, that will clue you in on what may be going wrong.